# Volume of revolution of a time versus distance graph

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light

If I plot a 'time elapsed' versus 'distance traveled' graph of a photon travelling in a vacuum (time on the vertical axis and distance on the horizontal) and then take the volume of revolution about the time axis, will it somehow correspond to what we call a light cone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right, with a few caveats:

- Technically, you should be talking about the *surface* of revolution, not the volume of revolution.  A light ray can't travel between an event $A$ and some other event $B$ that lies inside the cone $ds^2 = 0$.
- Spacetime is 4-D, and in higher dimensions, one can't talk about rotations "about an axis";  instead, one has to talk about rotations "within a plane".  Of course, one has to suppress one of the spatial dimensions to be able to draw this cone, so this point is a bit academic;  but it's still worth remembering that the light-cone is really a 3-D surface in a 4-D space.

Comment: It is possible use calculus with extra dimensions to talk about rotations within a plane?

Comment: @Coder511:  I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  But if you want to learn more about rotations in higher dimensions, there's a pretty good overview at this question:  [Why are the generators of rotation in the 4-dimensional Euclidean space correspond to rotations in a plane?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/376901/why-are-the-generators-of-rotation-in-the-4-dimensional-euclidean-space-correspo)